# SwiftUI : [Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix ERROR

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Expectation**: Green dot loading animation to occur when tapped on heart icon

**Outcome**: Nothing happens, feels like it freezes since the heart animation also doesn't work

**Error**: [Unknown process name] CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.

[Screenshot of the app(*not working state*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyJGZ.png)

**Code**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count=0
     @State var isPressed = false
    @State var pressed = false
    @State var isLoading = false
    var body: some View {
       
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill( isPressed ? Color(.systemGray4) : .red )
                    .overlay(Image(systemName:"heart.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(isPressed ? .red :.white)
                        .font(.system(size:100))
                        
                        .scaleEffect( pressed ? 1.5 : 1.0)
                )
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                
                
            }
            
            .onTapGesture{
                self.isLoading.toggle()
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 1,dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration :0.9)){
                self.isPressed.toggle()
                    self.pressed.toggle()
                    self.isLoading.toggle()
                }
                
            }
        
    
            HStack{
                ForEach(0...4, id: \.self){index in
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width:10,height:10)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .scaleEffect(self.isLoading ? 1:0)
                        .animation(Animation.linear(duration:0.6).repeatForever().delay(0.2*Double(index)))
                }
            }

        .padding()

            
    }
    
    }
    
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Note**: Loading animation works when I don't toggle the `isLoading` state variable inside `onTapGesture()` block and directly set it to true when the view appears inside `onAppear()` block

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**REASON :**

The problem is basically with **CGAffinTransform**

When you use the modifier **ScaleEffect** to your view, in background the compiler performs some short of Transforms on the scale Value that you have provided.

Since you have provided value 0 (zero) for .scaleEffect(), its taking the size as zero and treating it as a singular Matrix ( its a type of matrix whose Determinant is Zero ). and its also considered a mathematical violation to perform operations on matrices with a determinant of zero.

**SOLUTION :**

Make sure if you are using .scaleEffect() , don't scale the View to exact 0. You can use the smallest possible value i.e 0.1 or 0.01

Comment: If you need a very small non-zero value you can use `CGFloat.ulpOfOne`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in `0` scaleEffect.

Here is fixed code. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. Also corrected animation for the case of `isLoading = false`

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count=0
    @State var isPressed = false
    @State var pressed = false
    @State var isLoading = false
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .fill( isPressed ? Color(.systemGray4) : .red )
                    .overlay(Image(systemName:"heart.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(isPressed ? .red :.white)
                        .font(.system(size:100))

                        .scaleEffect( pressed ? 1.5 : 1.0)
                )
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            }
            .onTapGesture{
                self.isLoading.toggle()
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 1,dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration :0.9)){
                    self.isPressed.toggle()
                    self.pressed.toggle()
                }
            }

            HStack{
                ForEach(0...4, id: \.self){index in
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width:10,height:10)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .scaleEffect(self.isLoading ? 1:0.01)
                        .animation(self.isLoading ? Animation.linear(duration:0.6).repeatForever().delay(0.2*Double(index)) :
                            .default
                        )
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you tell me the reason why this was happening and how to prevent this in the future?